# React Native Vision Camera UseCodeScanner Error Exception

Tags: javascript, react-native, barcode-scanner, react-native-vision-camera

## I have an issue with the "useCodeScanner".

**ERROR  **TypeError: 0, _$$_REQUIRE(_dependencyMap[11(...)e-vision-camera").useCodeScanner is not a function (it is undefined)

This error is located at:
in Home (created by SceneView)
in StaticContainer
in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
in SceneView (created by SceneView)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by DebugContainer)
in DebugContainer (created by MaybeNestedStack)
in MaybeNestedStack (created by SceneView)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by SceneView)
in RNSScreen
in Unknown (created by InnerScreen)
in Suspender (created by Freeze)
in Suspense (created by Freeze)
in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
in DelayedFreeze (created by InnerScreen)
in InnerScreen (created by Screen)
in Screen (created by SceneView)
in SceneView (created by NativeStackViewInner)
in Suspender (created by Freeze)
in Suspense (created by Freeze)
in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
in DelayedFreeze (created by ScreenStack)
in RNSScreenStack (created by ScreenStack)
in ScreenStack (created by NativeStackViewInner)
in NativeStackViewInner (created by NativeStackView)
in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
in SafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext)
in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by NativeStackView)
in NativeStackView (created by NativeStackNavigator)
in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
in NavigationContent
in Unknown (created by NativeStackNavigator)
in NativeStackNavigator (created by App)
in EnsureSingleNavigator
in BaseNavigationContainer
in ThemeProvider
in NavigationContainerInner (created by App)
in App`your text`
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in AppContainer
in ScanEat(RootComponent), js engine: hermes
Do you have any ideas on how to fix it?
I really appreciate any help you can provide   .

```
 import {
  Camera,
  useCameraDevices,
  useCodeScanner,
} from 'react-native-vision-camera';
const devices = useCameraDevices();
  const device = devices.back;

  useEffect(() => {
    checkPermission();
  }, []);

  const checkPermission = async () => {
    try {
      const newCameraPermission = await Camera.requestCameraPermission();
      console.log('Camera Permission:', newCameraPermission);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Camera Permission Error:', error);
    }
  };

  
const codeScanner = useCodeScanner({
  codeTypes: ['qr', 'ean-13'],
  onCodeScanned: (codes) => {
    console.log(`Scanned ${codes.length} codes!`)
  }
})

  if (device == null) {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
        <ActivityIndicator />
      </View>
    );
  }  return (
    <SafeAreaView
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#000',
      }}>
      <Camera
        style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}
        device={device}
        isActive={true}
        codeScanner={codeScanner}
      />
  
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. However it seems like you are not familiar with the guide of Stack Overflow to [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read it and adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option. Happy coding!